SyntaxError: The requested module './src/app.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
I am developing a full stack project with node backend. I am a beginner in backend.
I faced an error in the code and unable to find out the solution. Here asking the developers to help me regarding this error.
Error desc:
file:///D:/MY-PROJECTS/REACT/Socialbook/server/server.js:1
import app from './src/app.js'
^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module './src/app.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

There is two files one main entry point 'server.js' another one is to handle the app i.e. 'app.js'.

server.js:

app.listen(process.env.SERVER_LISTENING_PORT, () =\> {
console.log(
"Server is listening on port : " + process.env.SERVER_LISTENING_PORT
);
});

app.js
dotenv.config();
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

// Importing Mongoose Models...
import connectMongoDB from "./config/mongoDB.js";
import {
loginController,
registerController,
} from "./controllers/entry/entryController.js";

const app = express();

connectMongoDB();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "10mb" }));
app.use(
cors({
origin: "http://localhost:3000",
methods: \["GET", "POST"\],
})
);

// user controllers
app.post("/register", registerController);

app.post("/login", loginController);

module.exports = app;

Here you can see I am trying to export the app and importing it in server.js
The below error is coming while compilation
import app from './src/app.js'
^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module './src/app.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
at ModuleJob.\_instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:132:21)
at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:214:5)
at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:34:7)
at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12)

Node.js v20.10.0

Error in console
If anyone having any solution please help me out. Thanks in advance.

App.js isn’t an esm module

Don't mix ES (import) and Commonjs (module.exports) modules, unless you know what you're doing. You can't do this in the same module any way

You need to change the export in app.js:
FROM module.exports = app;
TO export default app;
